# What am I doing wrong with this call to document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have the following javascript code

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
alert(myDiv);                
myDiv.style.display = 'none';
```

the call to **alert(myDiv)** succesfully shows that myDiv is not null and I see that the object (the div) has all the necessary properties set etc.

However, the call to **myDiv.style.display = none** results in an **Object Required** javascript error in IE 8.

Any pointers on what I need to check?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you put the HTML source of your div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your html markup is valid. You can use validation [service provided](http://validator.w3.org/) by w3c. Or if you are using any IDE check if it has validation facility

Comment: I double checked, and double checked, and double checked and you were right, I had a typo that was causing the problem.

Thanks :)

Comment: Most of the times if simple JavaScript DOM fails.. markup is the problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this script is called at `window.onload`, not before.

Edit: also, make sure you avoid the common pitfall of doing this:

```
window.onload = foo() # PROBABLY WRONG
```

When really you wanted to do this:

```
window.onload = foo
```

Comment: Hi, well I'm calling it at body.onload but I'll try your suggestion and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check that besides only attempting this after the DOM has loaded, that you don't have more than one element on the page with the same `myDiv` ID. View Source and try to find where this appears, make sure it isn't accidentally repeated.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

An html element will/can have id and name.
In my application we use master pages (asp.net) so when you place a control under a content page which is derived by master page,

> the **id** of the control will be like "ctl00_ctl00_ctlname"

and

> the **name** will have
>   "ctl00$ctl00$ctlname"

**Now,**
if getElementById works fine in IE7(IE 7) and not in IE8(IE 8)
then one possible reason is the value / attribute passed in getElementById method.
This is because IE7 used to find control by name if the id does not match.

> In short if you are passing the value
>   of name attribute then the
>   getElementById() will not work in IE8

happy coding :)